# Serenity-odt under ruby 2.0 Encoding::CompatibilityError

Tags: ruby, encoding

Here is an issue: [serenity-gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/serenity-odt) works perfectly under *ruby 1.8.7* but something happens under *ruby 2.0.0p195*. While using the same template and ruby-code it gives me the following error:

```
incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/serenity-odt-0.2.1/lib/serenity/generator.rb:5:in `render_odt'
/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/serenity-odt-0.2.1/lib/serenity/odteruby.rb:17:in `eval'
/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/serenity-odt-0.2.1/lib/serenity/odteruby.rb:17:in `evaluate'
/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/serenity-odt-0.2.1/lib/serenity/template.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/serenity-odt-0.2.1/lib/serenity/template.rb:16:in `each'
/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/serenity-odt-0.2.1/lib/serenity/template.rb:16:in `block in process'
/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rubyzip-0.9.9/lib/zip/zip_file.rb:90:in `open'
/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/serenity-odt-0.2.1/lib/serenity/template.rb:15:in `process'
/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/serenity-odt-0.2.1/lib/serenity/generator.rb:5:in `render_odt'
```

This solutions have no effect for me: [github](https://github.com/kremso/serenity/pull/11/files), [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15367479).

My environment: Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS x86_64 3.2.0-49-generic, rvm 1.21.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding string `content = content.force_encoding('UTF-8')` in **/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/serenity-odt-0.2.1/lib/serenity/template.rb**

```
def process context
  tmpfiles = []
  Zip::ZipFile.open(@template) do |zipfile|
    %w(content.xml styles.xml).each do |xml_file|
      content = zipfile.read(xml_file)
      content = content.force_encoding('UTF-8')
      odteruby = OdtEruby.new(XmlReader.new(content))
      out = odteruby.evaluate(context)

      tmpfiles << (file = Tempfile.new("serenity"))
      file << out
      file.close

      zipfile.replace(xml_file, file.path)
    end
  end
end
```

I got the inspiration from [here](http://blog.rayapps.com/2013/03/11/7-things-that-can-go-wrong-with-ruby-19-string-encodings/).